# "tickPositions is undefined" after adding a second Y-Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart that throws an error in the addSeries method when there are two Y-axes.

This is a Backbone project so I have simplified the code in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michalcarson/V84pP/.

The code creates a chart with no data.  It adds a second Y-axis.  Then it adds the data for the first series.  The error occurs at that point:  "TypeError: tickPositions is undefined" in highcharts.src.js line 7315.

The data I'm adding should be associated with the primary y-axis (chart.yAxis[0]) but the error occurs whether I specify that association or not.  See the JSFiddle for more detail.

```
var chart,
options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chartdiv'
    }
},

real_series = {
    "data": [10.816667, 8.458333, 9.1, 8.794771, 7.91789, 7.281212,
        6.671075, 6.08748, 5.530427, 4.999916, 4.495946, 4.018517, 3.567631]
};

chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

chart.addAxis({
    id: "LCUReal",
    title: { text: "LCU Real" },
    opposite: true
}, false);

chart.addSeries(real_series);
```

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 and Highcharts 4.0.3.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/4.0.3/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

So the question is: What's wrong with this code?  How do I get a second Y-axis working without this error?

I'm not doing anything with tickPositions.  I've never had to before.  I'm happy to let Highcharts work that out.

Comment: Can you please provide link to such an example that is working correctly, so that by comparing I can see what is wrong with your code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found I can make this work if I defer creating the secondary y-axis until it is needed.  That is,

- add the primary y-axis,
- add data series using the primary y-axis,
- add the secondary y-axis,
- add data series using the secondary y-axis.

Corrected code:

```
var chart,
options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chartdiv'
    }
},

series1 = {
    "name": "Interest Rate %",
    "data": [10.816667, 8.458333, 9.1, 8.794771, 7.91789, 7.281212,
    6.671075, 6.08748, 5.530427, 4.999916, 4.495946, 4.018517, 3.567631],
    "yAxis": "%"
},
series2 = {
    "name": "Exports",
    "data": [5803.475611, 5820.886038, 5925.661986, 6022.908979, 6091.005915, 6133.429061, 
             6158.918132, 6174.863244, 6186.050828, 6195.144854, 6203.458226, 6211.561078, 6219.661642],
     "yAxis": "LCUReal"
};

chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

chart.yAxis[0].update({
    id: "%",
    title: { text: "%" }
});

// SOLUTION: adding series1 here prevents the error
chart.addSeries(series1);

chart.addAxis({
    id: "LCUReal",
    title: {
        text: "LCU Real"
    },
    opposite: true
}, false);

// PROBLEM: adding secondary y-axis before adding data series to the primary y-axis throws 
//          TypeError: tickPositions is undefined.
// PROBLEM: even if the data is added above before the secondary y-axis is created, adding 
//          a series to the primary y-axis when there is no data on the secondary y-axis
//          will throw the same TypeError: tickPositions is undefined.
//chart.addSeries(series1);
chart.addSeries(series2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your axis has no range, you can get rid of it by linking your axis with first one.

Example:

```
chart.addAxis({
            linkedTo: 0,
            id: "LCUReal",
            title: {
                text: "LCU Real"
            },
            opposite: true
        }, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sFfrL/8/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian.  That makes the code run but the next data series will need quite a different scale.

Comment: Yep. Your fiddle shows the same solution that I came to: use the primary y-axis before adding a secondary y-axis. Thanks again.